# Django-tables2 add html attribute to column

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I have an Imagefield in a model, in my table that field is displayed as a link but when you click on it, it directs to a the url and instead I want to do download it. I foud that in html you can add the "download" attribute like this:

```
<a href="/media/pictures/CFE.JPG" download></a>
```

so in my django-tables2:

> tables.py

```
class PagosDetailTable(tables.Table):

    imagen = tables.Column(
        attrs={"td": {"href": "download"}})

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
        fields = ('carro', 'semana', 'fecha', 'pago', 'imagen')
        attrs = {"class": "table table-hover table-sm"}
```

but that it overrides the href:

```
<a href="download"></a>
```

is there a way to append the download attribute using the tables.Column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for my issue:

> tables.py

```
class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return format_html('<a href="/media/{}" download>Imagen</a>', value)


class PagosDetailTable(tables.Table):
    imagen = ImageColumn()

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
        fields = ('carro', 'semana', 'fecha', 'pago')
        attrs = {"class": "table table-hover table-sm"}
```

Comment: Hi, it is a Function for building small html fragments, you can find more information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/